# Cannot delete array from object populated by sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I cannot `delete` or change the value of `books` attribute of `library` object.

```
Library.findOne(12).populate('books').populate('createdBy').exec(
    function(err,library) {

        delete library.createdBy;
        //worked

        delete library.name;
        //worked

        delete library.books;
        //no effect

        library.books = [];
        //worked

        library.books = [{a:'any val'}];
        //just like library.books=[]

        console.log(library);
    });
```

My model for library for books and createdBy is like

```
createdBy: {
    model: "createdBy"
},
books: {
    collection: "books",
    via: "library",
    dominant: true
}
```

I cannot figured out what is happening here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`delete library.books;` does not work because associations are not fields in the model object. Associations actually live in an `associations` object and read/write operations are done through custom getters/setters. You can see more about this behaviour in [waterline/model/lib/internalMethods/defineAssociations.js#L109](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/4653f8a18016d2bcde9a70c90dd63a7c69381935/lib/waterline/model/lib/internalMethods/defineAssociations.js#L109):

```
Define.prototype.buildHasManyProperty = function(collection) {
  var self = this;

  // Attach to a non-enumerable property
  this.proto.associations[collection] = new Association();

  // Attach getter and setter to the model
  Object.defineProperty(this.proto, collection, {
    set: function(val) { self.proto.associations[collection]._setValue(val); },
    get: function() { return self.proto.associations[collection]._getValue(); },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  });
};
```

Hope that helps.

Is this causing a problem? This can be avoided by not populating associations in the first place. Doing `model.toObject()` or `model.toJSON()` and delete the association field afterwards should also work.